# Passing a variable through _GET

Tags: php

I am trying to pass a variable through a GET request (which i am defining myself).

So my variable stores a url, and if someone passes d = site.com it should allow access. if not, it should fail. The only thing that is failing is passing the variable through the get

Doesnt Work:

```
    $redirect = site();
    $parse = parse_url($redirect);
    $next = $parse['host'];

    if ($_GET['cld'] !== $next ) redirect();
```

Does Work (static, not dynamic, so it doesnt get the URL)

```
    $redirect = site();
    $parse = parse_url($redirect);
    $next = $parse['host'];

    if ($_GET['d'] !== 'site') redirect();
```

Comment: Isn't that just because `'site.com' != 'site'`, or that `'cld'!='d'` or are those just errors in the example?

Comment: @Wrikken Just edited my post with the entire code.

Comment: OK, then: `$_GET['cld'] !== $d` equals `'site.com' !== '.com'` in your case?

Comment: So the parse is to parse the URL that im getting, strip out all the junk i dont need (http, www, .co.uk, .com etc..). Now within the url of the site i am passing a variable cld and now the second variable should be the site name e.g. google so it should be like cld=google otherwise 302.

Comment: I see no stripping out of tld's... `parse_url()` would return `google.com` as host, not `google`, and `$d` still only contains `.com` at the point of check as far as I can see. Are you trying to do something like `if($_GET['cld'] !== substr($next,0, -1 * strlen($d)))` ?

Comment: @Wrikken Yes that is why i was passing the $super array through the strpos function through foreach to go through each element and clean out the last bit of the domain extension. I have posted by answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

Passed it through a foreach and returned the value d and then called it in my function.

```
    foreach($super as $d){
        if (strpos($next, $d) !== false) {
            return $d;
        }
    }

    if ($_GET['cld'] !== $d ) wp_redirect();
```